# How do I display integers in hexadecimal, from a batch file?

Tags: windows, math, batch-file, integer

```
echo The error level is: %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Produces

```
>The error level is: 15
```

What I would like:

```
>The error level is: F
```

do I need to do conversions or is there a way to display numbers differently?

Any help in the right direction is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write it in vbscript instead of batch

put the vbscript statement below into a file.

```
WScript.Echo Hex( WScript.Arguments(0) )
```

then to run it, simple type this on the command line ( in a batch script, use a for loop to capture the value if required )

```
C:\workspace> cscript //nologo hex.vbs 15
F
```

There is no need to install anything. vbscript comes by default in most windows systems.

Answer (score 9):

It was a long time ago, I was very bored.

**cmdcalc.cmd**

```
@echo off
    if not defined trace set trace=rem
    %trace% on
SetLocal
    if "%1"=="/?" (
       call :help %0
       goto :eof
    )
    Set MinInBase=
    if /i "%2" EQU "Bin" call :DoBin %1
    if /i "%2" EQU "Hex" call :DoHex %1
    If not defined BinStr call :DoDec %1
EndLocal & set RET=%RET%
goto :eof


:DoBin
    Set MinInBase=2
    Set ShiftBy=1
    Set StartSyn=0b
    call :DoCalc %1
goto :eof

:DoHex
    Set MinInBase=16
    Set ShiftBy=4
    Set StartSyn=0x
    call :DoCalc %1
goto :eof


:DoDec
    if {%1} EQU {} goto :eof
    set  /a BinStr=%1
    set RET=%BinStr%
    echo %RET%
goto :eof


:DoCalc 
    Set BinStr= 
    SET /A A=%1
    %Trace% %A%
:StartSplit
    SET /A B="A>>%ShiftBy%"
    %Trace% %B%
    SET /A C="B<<%ShiftBy%"
    %Trace% %C%
    SET /A C=A-C
    %Trace% %C%
    call :StringIt %C%
    If %B% LSS %MinInBase% goto :EndSplit 
    set A=%B%
goto :StartSplit    
:EndSplit
    call :StringIt %B%
    set RET=%StartSyn%%BinStr%
    Echo %RET%
EndLocal & set RET=%RET%
goto :eof


:StringIt
    set Bin=0123456789ABCDEF
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('echo "%%BIN:~%1,1%%"') do set RET=%%A
    set ret=%ret:"=%
    Set BinStr=%Ret%%BinStr%
goto :eof

:help
    echo %1 syntax:
    echo.
    echo %1 Calculation [Hex^|Bin]
    echo.
    echo eg %1 12*2 Hex
    echo.
    echo gives 0x18.
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the external resource [Windows Environment Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), there is an undocumented built-in read-only variable `=ExitCode` which returns the current exit code in hexadecimal format. To ensure the `ErrorLevel` value equals the exit code, use `cmd /C exit %ErrorLevel%`.

So if you are using this line code...:

```
cmd /C exit %ErrorLevel%
echo The error level is: %=ExitCode%
```

...you will receive this (supposing the `ErrorLevel` is `15`):

> ```
> The error level is: 0000000F
> ```

To get rid of the leading zeros, use this...:

```
cmd /C exit %ErrorLevel%
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%=ExitCode%") do set "HEXCODE=%%Z"
if not defined HEXCODE set "HEXCODE=0"
echo The error level is: %HEXCODE%
```

...to get this:

> ```
> The error level is: F
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
perl -e"printf qq{The errorlevel is: %X\n}, $ENV{ERRORLEVEL}"
```

Requires [Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) to be installed, of course, but that's easy to do.

Comment: It's only easy to do if you're admin on your own machine. Out there in the real world all kinds of things are in the way of »just installing something«.

Comment: @Joey, I have got at least 5 installs of Perl on both of my machines. I didn't need any admin privileges on the non-Windows machine. I don't remember for the Windows machine, but I don't see why you'd need any special privileges. It can be installed to any directory, and it doesn't need the registry.