# Format a hexadecimal sequence in a cmd.exe batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, hex, string-formatting

In a Windows cmd script (aka bat script), I have a [FOR /L](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) loop from 1 to 8, where I need to [do a bit shift](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and somehow format a variable as a hexadecimal number (which if you ask, is a single CPU identifier bit to [feed into `/AFFINITY`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7759948/327026)).

I can't figure out how to do the last step. This is my `loop.cmd` file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,8) DO (
    SET /A "J=1<<%%i"
    ECHO %%i and !J!
)
```

which does everything but format a hex number:

```
1 and 2
2 and 4
3 and 8
4 and 16
5 and 32
6 and 64
7 and 128
8 and 256
```

expected output is:

```
1 and 2
2 and 4
3 and 8
4 and 10
5 and 20
6 and 40
7 and 80
8 and 100
```

How do you format a hexadecimal number?

Comment: If you are stuck using only batch, there is a solution posted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737658/how-do-i-display-integers-in-hexadecimal-from-a-batch-file

Comment: You can find a simple solution for decimal-to-hexadecimal number conversion there: [hexadecimal to decimal batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33027661)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,8) DO (
    SET /A "J=1<<%%i"
    CALL :DECTOHEX J
    ECHO %%i and !J!
)
GOTO :EOF

:DECTOHEX VAR
SET "DEC=!%1!"
SET "HEX="
:NEXT
    SET /A DIGIT=DEC%%16, DEC/=16
    SET "HEX=%DIGIT%%HEX%"
IF %DEC% NEQ 0 GOTO NEXT
SET "%1=%HEX%"
EXIT /B
```

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comment*

Previous solution works correctly when the shifted value have just one bit on, *as stated in the question*. If the shifted value may have several bits on then a more general decimal-to-hexadecimal conversion is required, like the one below:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM DEFINE THE HEXA DIGITS
SET "HEXA=0123456789ABCDEF"

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,8) DO (
    SET /A "J=3<<%%i"
    CALL :DECTOHEX J
    ECHO %%i and !J!
)
GOTO :EOF

:DECTOHEX VAR
SET "DEC=!%1!"
SET "HEX="
:NEXT
    SET /A DIGIT=DEC%%16, DEC/=16
    SET "HEX=!HEXA:~%DIGIT%,1!%HEX%"
IF %DEC% NEQ 0 GOTO NEXT
SET "%1=%HEX%"
EXIT /B
```

Comment: While it works for the example in the question, it does not properly convert to hex, e.g. I'm trying a new bitmask for two processors with `SET /A "J=3<<%%i"` where base-10 192 should be hex c0, and not hex 120 using the current DECTOHEX method.

Comment: Of course. This solution was written based on the original request: a value with _one bit on_ that is shifted to the left. If the shifted value may have _several bits on_, why you didn't stated this point from the very beginning? **`:(`**. See the edit in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=2
set n=1
set /a result=n
for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do (
  set /a result*=x
  if "!result:~0,1!"=="1" set result=!result:16=10!
  echo %%a and !result!
)
```

output:

```
1 and 2
2 and 4
3 and 8
4 and 10
5 and 20
6 and 40
7 and 80
8 and 100
9 and 200
10 and 400
```

Comment: I'm unable to adapt this to use bit shifts, as specified in the question.