# hexadecimal to decimal batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

okay so I have been working an a batch file that converts a base ten decimal value in to hexadecimal but I can't get the for loops and the if statements down right every were I look seems to be giving me the wrong information here is my code. thank you to all that reply

```
@ echo off
echo Hexa Decimal Convertor 1.0

set OneOn = false
set TwoOn = false
set ThreeOn = false
set FourOn = false
set FiveOn = false
set SixOn = false
set SevenOn = false
set EightOn = false

set firstDig = 0
set secondDig = 0


set digits =  128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 0

set Total = 0
set INPUT = 43

set /p INPUT=Enter a number (0-255): 
if %INPUT% gtr 15 goto other
if %INPUT% == 1 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = %INPUT%
if %INPUT% == 2 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = %INPUT%
if %INPUT% == 3 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = %INPUT%
if %INPUT% == 4 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = %INPUT%
if %INPUT% == 5 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = %INPUT%
if %INPUT% == 6 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = %INPUT%
if %INPUT% == 7 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = %INPUT%
if %INPUT% == 8 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = %INPUT%
if %INPUT% == 9 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = %INPUT%
if %INPUT% == 10 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = A
if %INPUT% == 11 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = B
if %INPUT% == 12 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = C
if %INPUT% == 13 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = D
if %INPUT% == 14 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = E
if %INPUT% == 15 echo IN HEXADECIMAL %INPUT% = F
pause
:other
for /l %%G (0, 1, 8) do (
    for /l %%F (0,1,8) do (
        for /l %%D (0,1,8) do (
            for /l %%S (0,1,8) do (
                for /l %%A (0,1,8) do (
                    for /l %%L (0,1,8) do (
                        for /l %%K (0,1,8) do (
                            for /l %%J (0,1,8) do (
                                for /l %%H (0,1,8) do (

                                    set TESTTOTAL = digit[%H%] + digit[%J%] + digit[%K%] +  digit[%L%] +  digit[%A%] + digit[%S%] + digit[%D%] + digit[%F%] + digit[%G%]
                                    if %TESTTOTAL% == %INPUT% goto match 

                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

:match
if digit[%H%] == 1 OneOn = true
if digit[%H%] == 2 TwoOn = true
if digit[%H%] == 4 ThreeOn = true
if digit[%H%] == 8 FourOn = true
if digit[%H%] == 16 FiveOn = true
if digit[%H%] == 32 SixOn = true
if digit[%H%] == 64 SevenOn = true
if digit[%H%] == 128 EightOn = true 

if digit[%J%] == 1 OneOn = true
if digit[%J%] == 2 TwoOn = true
if digit[%J%] == 4 ThreeOn = true
if digit[%J%] == 8 FourOn = true
if digit[%J%] == 16 FiveOn = true
if digit[%J%] == 32 SixOn = true
if digit[%J%] == 64 SevenOn = true
if digit[%J%] == 128 EightOn = true

if digit[%K%] == 1 OneOn = true
if digit[%K%] == 2 TwoOn = true
if digit[%K%] == 4 ThreeOn = true
if digit[%K%] == 8 FourOn = true
if digit[%K%] == 16 FiveOn = true
if digit[%K%] == 32 SixOn = true
if digit[%K%] == 64 SevenOn = true
if digit[%K%] == 128 EightOn = true

if digit[%L%] == 1 OneOn = true
if digit[%L%] == 2 TwoOn = true
if digit[%L%] == 4 ThreeOn = true
if digit[%L%] == 8 FourOn = true
if digit[%L%] == 16 FiveOn = true
if digit[%L%] == 32 SixOn = true
if digit[%L%] == 64 SevenOn = true
if digit[%L%] == 128 EightOn = true

if digit[%A%] == 1 OneOn = true
if digit[%A%] == 2 TwoOn = true
if digit[%A%] == 4 ThreeOn = true
if digit[%A%] == 8 FourOn = true
if digit[%A%] == 16 FiveOn = true
if digit[%A%] == 32 SixOn = true
if digit[%A%] == 64 SevenOn = true
if digit[%A%] == 128 EightOn = true

if digit[%S%] == 1 OneOn = true
if digit[%S%] == 2 TwoOn = true
if digit[%S%] == 4 ThreeOn = true
if digit[%S%] == 8 FourOn = true
if digit[%S%] == 16 FiveOn = true
if digit[%S%] == 32 SixOn = true
if digit[%S%] == 64 SevenOn = true
if digit[%S%] == 128 EightOn = true

if digit[%D%] == 1 OneOn = true
if digit[%D%] == 2 TwoOn = true
if digit[%D%] == 4 ThreeOn = true
if digit[%D%] == 8 FourOn = true
if digit[%D%] == 16 FiveOn = true
if digit[%D%] == 32 SixOn = true
if digit[%D%] == 64 SevenOn = true
if digit[%D%] == 128 EightOn = true

if digit[%F%] == 1 OneOn = true
if digit[%F%] == 2 TwoOn = true
if digit[%F%] == 4 ThreeOn = true
if digit[%F%] == 8 FourOn = true
if digit[%F%] == 16 FiveOn = true
if digit[%F%] == 32 SixOn = true
if digit[%F%] == 64 SevenOn = true
if digit[%F%] == 128 EightOn = true

if digit[%G%] == 1 OneOn = true
if digit[%G%] == 2 TwoOn = true
if digit[%G%] == 4 ThreeOn = true
if digit[%G%] == 8 FourOn = true
if digit[%G%] == 16 FiveOn = true
if digit[%G%] == 32 SixOn = true
if digit[%G%] == 64 SevenOn = true
if digit[%G%] == 128 EightOn = true

if OneOn == true & TwoOn == true & ThreeOn == true & FourOn == true secondDig = F
if OneOn == true & TwoOn == true & ThreeOn == true & FourOn == false secondDig = E
if OneOn == true & TwoOn == true & ThreeOn == false & FourOn == true secondDig = D
if OneOn == false & TwoOn == false & ThreeOn == true & FourOn == true secondDig = C
if OneOn == true & TwoOn == true & ThreeOn == false & FourOn == true secondDig = B
if OneOn == false & TwoOn == true & ThreeOn == false & FourOn == true secondDig = A
if OneOn == true & TwoOn == false & ThreeOn == false & FourOn == true secondDig = 9
if OneOn == false & TwoOn == false & ThreeOn == false & FourOn == true secondDig = 8
if OneOn == true & TwoOn == true & ThreeOn == true & FourOn == false secondDig = 7
if OneOn == false & TwoOn == true & ThreeOn == true & FourOn == false secondDig = 6
if OneOn == true & TwoOn == false & ThreeOn == true & FourOn == false secondDig = 5
if OneOn == false & TwoOn == false & ThreeOn == true & FourOn == false secondDig = 4
if OneOn == true & TwoOn == true & ThreeOn == false & FourOn == false secondDig = 3
if OneOn == false & TwoOn == true & ThreeOn == false & FourOn == false secondDig = 2
if OneOn == true & TwoOn == false & ThreeOn == false & FourOn == false secondDig = 1
if OneOn == false & TwoOn == false & ThreeOn == false & FourOn == false secondDig = 0

if FiveOn == true & SixOn == true & SevenOn == true & EightOn == true firstDig = F
if FiveOn == true & SixOn == true & SevenOn == true & EightOn == false firstDig = E
if FiveOn == true & SixOn == true & SevenOn == false & EightOn == true firstDig = D
if FiveOn == false & SixOn == false & SevenOn == true & EightOn == true firstDig = C
if FiveOn == true & SixOn == true & SevenOn == false & EightOn == true firstDig = B
if FiveOn == false & SixOn == true & SevenOn == false & EightOn == true firstDig = A
if FiveOn == true & SixOn == false & SevenOn == false & EightOn == true firstDig = 9
if FiveOn == false & SixOn == false & SevenOn == false & EightOn == true firstDig = 8
if FiveOn == true & SixOn == true & SevenOn == true & EightOn == false firstDig = 7
if FiveOn == false & SixOn == true & SevenOn == true & EightOn == false firstDig = 6
if FiveOn == true & SixOn == false & SevenOn == true & EightOn == false firstDig = 5
if FiveOn == false & SixOn == false & SevenOn == true & EightOn == false firstDig = 4
if FiveOn == true & SixOn == true & SevenOn == false & EightOn == false firstDig = 3
if FiveOn == false & SixOn == true & SevenOn == false & EightOn == false firstDig = 2
if FiveOn == true & SixOn == false & SevenOn == false & EightOn == false firstDig = 1
if FiveOn == false & SixOn == false & SevenOn == false & EightOn == false firstDig = 0

echo in hexadecimal %INPUT% = %firstDig% %secondDig%  
pause
```

Comment: The second search result I found in Google for `convert decimal to hex batch file` was [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2011/06/29/hex-conversion-via-a-batch-file.aspx), which seems to work just fine.

Comment: @KenWhite but here is supposed to be `hexadecimal` to `decimal`

Comment: Code in the link I provided does both (hex to decimal or decimal to hex). Searching for `convert hex to decimal batch file` turns up the same exact link I posted. Did you *read it*?

Comment: @KenWhite Google does not always tell the truth. It was not because he return you the same link when you mix the words that means be relevant. And yes I have tested the link. For example it convert 255 to 0xFF but not the opposite.

Comment: OK. Sorry for trying to help you learn how to search Google. Whether it turned up the same result as second or not is irrelevant - what matters is **it turned up the same result**. The **code is relevant** for doing both conversions, as I said before.

Comment: @KenWhite Have you at least tried the code from the link you provided and are we talking about the same link? You are mistaken

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961479/format-a-hexadecimal-sequence-in-a-cmd-exe-batch-file/32967341#32967341

Comment: There is also http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsArithmetic.php#toDec

Comment: @user1610489 Please edit the question to make clear what you really want to do. The title is about __hexadecimal to decimal__ but in first sentence in body you wrote __decimal to hexadecimal__. So what is your batch file really for? Do you know that every Windows has `calc`, a calculator which when set to Programmer (Windows Vista or later) or Scientific (Windows XP and before) can convert decimal numbers to hexadecimal (key F5) and vice versa (key F6) and also octal (F7) and binary (F8)? Sysinternals [Hex2dec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896736) can be used on cmd line.

Answer (score 12):

*Supposing you want to convert **hexadecimal to decimal** numbers:*

Why not simply using `set /A` to do the job on its own? `set /A` is capable of converting hexadecimal to decimal numbers when prefixed with `0x`. See `set /?` for details.
The line below stores the decimal number in `DEC`, supposing `HEX` contains a hexadecimal number:

```
set /A DEC=0x%HEX%
```

The following script prompts the user for a hex. number and displays its decimal representation:

```
@echo off
:LOOP
set "HEX="
set /P "HEX=Enter a hexadecimal number (up to 8 digits): "
if not defined HEX goto :EOF
set /A DEC=0x%HEX%
echo The decimal representation of %HEX% is %DEC%.
goto :LOOP
```

Note that the hexadecimal number is limited to 8 digits (32 bits), and it is interpreted as signed value.

---

*Supposing you want to convert **decimal to hexadecimal** numbers:*

There is an undocumented [built-in environment variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) called `=ExitCode` that holds the hexadecimal character code (ASCII) of the current return or exit code (usually the `ErrorLevel`).
The lines below store the hexadecimal number in `HEX`, supposing `DEC` contains a decimal number:

```
cmd /C exit %DEC%
set "HEX=%=ExitCode%"
```

The following script prompts the user for a decimal number and displays its hex. representation:

```
@echo off
:LOOP
set "DEC="
set /P "DEC=Enter a decimal number (signed 32-bit integer): "
if not defined DEC goto :EOF
cmd /C exit %DEC%
set "HEX=%=ExitCode%"
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%HEX%") do set "HEX=%%Z"
if not defined HEX set "HEX=0"
echo The hexadecimal representation of %DEC% is %HEX%.
goto :LOOP
```

Comment: Thank you for the great tactics here, it saved my day. When I turned to chatgpt, it told me "there is no way to convert dec to hex in pure batch". Human still prevails!

Comment: @EricSun, besides leveraging the above mentioned undocumented quirks, you could always write a script that converts the numbers like one would do on paper, which could also be done in pure batch (basically using a `for`-loop and `set /A`). So I'd say there is always a way… 

Answer (score 4):

Phew - what a lot of Code. This is a little bit shorter:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "hex=0123456789ABCDEF"
set /p INPUT=Enter a number (0-255):
set /a high=%INPUT% / 16
set /a low=%INPUT% %% 16
echo in hexadecimal %INPUT% = !hex:~%high%,1! !hex:~%low%,1!
```

Comment: You may use just one SET /A command: `set /a high=INPUT / 16, low=INPUT %% 16`  **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini yes, and save a few spaces, but I like to keep things readable (this is not tagged [code golf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) `;)`)

Answer (score 2):

Save this with `.bat` extension:

```
@if (@x)==(@y) @end /***** jscript comment ******
     @echo off

     cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
     exit /b 0

 @if (@x)==(@y) @end ******  end comment *********/

 var args=WScript.Arguments;
 var number=args.Item(0);

 WScript.Echo(parseInt(number,16));
```

And use it like

```
for /f %%# in ('hexToDec.bat 10E4') do set "decimalNumber=%%#"
echo %decimalNumber%
```

Comment: The same in one line! **`:-)`**  `@set @a=0 /* & CScript //E:JScript //nologo "%~F0" %* & exit /b 0 */ WScript.Echo(parseInt(WScript.Arguments(0),16));`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on aschipfl's answer but in the form of a ready to use batch file subfunction and even a demo function

Here it is

Save as
HexToDecimal-demo.bat

```
@echo off

Call :HexToDecimal-DEMO
GoTo :EOF

:HexToDecimal-DEMO
set /a "_HexToDecimal_demo_limit=255"
set /a "_HexToDecimal_demo_index=0"
:HexToDecimal-DEMO-loop
set /a "_HexToDecimal_demo_original=%_HexToDecimal_demo_index%"
Call :DecimalToHex _HexToDecimal_demo_dec2hex _HexToDecimal_demo_original
Call :HexToDecimal _HexToDecimal_demo_hex2dec _HexToDecimal_demo_dec2hex
echo original %_HexToDecimal_demo_original% dec2hex %_HexToDecimal_demo_dec2hex% hex2dec %_HexToDecimal_demo_hex2dec%
set /a "_HexToDecimal_demo_index+=1"
if %_HexToDecimal_demo_index% LEQ %_HexToDecimal_demo_limit% GoTo :HexToDecimal-DEMO-loop
GoTo :EOF

::Usage Call :HexToDecimal OutputVariable Input
:HexToDecimal
set "_HexToDecimal_output=%~1"
set "_HexToDecimal_input=%~2"
if defined %~2 ( call set "_HexToDecimal_input=%%%~2%%" ) 
if "[%_HexToDecimal_input:~0,2%]" NEQ "[0x]" set "_HexToDecimal_input=0x%_HexToDecimal_input%"
set /a "%~1=%_HexToDecimal_input%"
GoTo :EOF

::Usage Call :DecimalToHex OutputVariable Input
:DecimalToHex
set "_DecimalToHex_output=%~1"
set "_DecimalToHex_input=%~2"
if defined %~2 ( call set "_DecimalToHex_input=%%%~2%%" ) 
cmd /C exit %_DecimalToHex_input%
set "%~1=%=ExitCode%"
GoTo :EOF
```

Here is the console output this code will produce

```
HexToDecimal-demo.bat
original 0 dec2hex 00000000 hex2dec 0
original 1 dec2hex 00000001 hex2dec 1
original 2 dec2hex 00000002 hex2dec 2
original 3 dec2hex 00000003 hex2dec 3
original 4 dec2hex 00000004 hex2dec 4
original 5 dec2hex 00000005 hex2dec 5
original 6 dec2hex 00000006 hex2dec 6
original 7 dec2hex 00000007 hex2dec 7
original 8 dec2hex 00000008 hex2dec 8
original 9 dec2hex 00000009 hex2dec 9
original 10 dec2hex 0000000A hex2dec 10
original 11 dec2hex 0000000B hex2dec 11
original 12 dec2hex 0000000C hex2dec 12
original 13 dec2hex 0000000D hex2dec 13
original 14 dec2hex 0000000E hex2dec 14
original 15 dec2hex 0000000F hex2dec 15
original 16 dec2hex 00000010 hex2dec 16
original 17 dec2hex 00000011 hex2dec 17
original 18 dec2hex 00000012 hex2dec 18
original 19 dec2hex 00000013 hex2dec 19
original 20 dec2hex 00000014 hex2dec 20
original 21 dec2hex 00000015 hex2dec 21
original 22 dec2hex 00000016 hex2dec 22
original 23 dec2hex 00000017 hex2dec 23
original 24 dec2hex 00000018 hex2dec 24
original 25 dec2hex 00000019 hex2dec 25
original 26 dec2hex 0000001A hex2dec 26
original 27 dec2hex 0000001B hex2dec 27
original 28 dec2hex 0000001C hex2dec 28
original 29 dec2hex 0000001D hex2dec 29
original 30 dec2hex 0000001E hex2dec 30
original 31 dec2hex 0000001F hex2dec 31
original 32 dec2hex 00000020 hex2dec 32
original 33 dec2hex 00000021 hex2dec 33
original 34 dec2hex 00000022 hex2dec 34
original 35 dec2hex 00000023 hex2dec 35
original 36 dec2hex 00000024 hex2dec 36
original 37 dec2hex 00000025 hex2dec 37
original 38 dec2hex 00000026 hex2dec 38
original 39 dec2hex 00000027 hex2dec 39
original 40 dec2hex 00000028 hex2dec 40
original 41 dec2hex 00000029 hex2dec 41
original 42 dec2hex 0000002A hex2dec 42
original 43 dec2hex 0000002B hex2dec 43
original 44 dec2hex 0000002C hex2dec 44
original 45 dec2hex 0000002D hex2dec 45
original 46 dec2hex 0000002E hex2dec 46
original 47 dec2hex 0000002F hex2dec 47
original 48 dec2hex 00000030 hex2dec 48
original 49 dec2hex 00000031 hex2dec 49
original 50 dec2hex 00000032 hex2dec 50
original 51 dec2hex 00000033 hex2dec 51
original 52 dec2hex 00000034 hex2dec 52
original 53 dec2hex 00000035 hex2dec 53
original 54 dec2hex 00000036 hex2dec 54
original 55 dec2hex 00000037 hex2dec 55
original 56 dec2hex 00000038 hex2dec 56
original 57 dec2hex 00000039 hex2dec 57
original 58 dec2hex 0000003A hex2dec 58
original 59 dec2hex 0000003B hex2dec 59
original 60 dec2hex 0000003C hex2dec 60
original 61 dec2hex 0000003D hex2dec 61
original 62 dec2hex 0000003E hex2dec 62
original 63 dec2hex 0000003F hex2dec 63
original 64 dec2hex 00000040 hex2dec 64
original 65 dec2hex 00000041 hex2dec 65
original 66 dec2hex 00000042 hex2dec 66
original 67 dec2hex 00000043 hex2dec 67
original 68 dec2hex 00000044 hex2dec 68
original 69 dec2hex 00000045 hex2dec 69
original 70 dec2hex 00000046 hex2dec 70
original 71 dec2hex 00000047 hex2dec 71
original 72 dec2hex 00000048 hex2dec 72
original 73 dec2hex 00000049 hex2dec 73
original 74 dec2hex 0000004A hex2dec 74
original 75 dec2hex 0000004B hex2dec 75
original 76 dec2hex 0000004C hex2dec 76
original 77 dec2hex 0000004D hex2dec 77
original 78 dec2hex 0000004E hex2dec 78
original 79 dec2hex 0000004F hex2dec 79
original 80 dec2hex 00000050 hex2dec 80
original 81 dec2hex 00000051 hex2dec 81
original 82 dec2hex 00000052 hex2dec 82
original 83 dec2hex 00000053 hex2dec 83
original 84 dec2hex 00000054 hex2dec 84
original 85 dec2hex 00000055 hex2dec 85
original 86 dec2hex 00000056 hex2dec 86
original 87 dec2hex 00000057 hex2dec 87
original 88 dec2hex 00000058 hex2dec 88
original 89 dec2hex 00000059 hex2dec 89
original 90 dec2hex 0000005A hex2dec 90
original 91 dec2hex 0000005B hex2dec 91
original 92 dec2hex 0000005C hex2dec 92
original 93 dec2hex 0000005D hex2dec 93
original 94 dec2hex 0000005E hex2dec 94
original 95 dec2hex 0000005F hex2dec 95
original 96 dec2hex 00000060 hex2dec 96
original 97 dec2hex 00000061 hex2dec 97
original 98 dec2hex 00000062 hex2dec 98
original 99 dec2hex 00000063 hex2dec 99
original 100 dec2hex 00000064 hex2dec 100
original 101 dec2hex 00000065 hex2dec 101
original 102 dec2hex 00000066 hex2dec 102
original 103 dec2hex 00000067 hex2dec 103
original 104 dec2hex 00000068 hex2dec 104
original 105 dec2hex 00000069 hex2dec 105
original 106 dec2hex 0000006A hex2dec 106
original 107 dec2hex 0000006B hex2dec 107
original 108 dec2hex 0000006C hex2dec 108
original 109 dec2hex 0000006D hex2dec 109
original 110 dec2hex 0000006E hex2dec 110
original 111 dec2hex 0000006F hex2dec 111
original 112 dec2hex 00000070 hex2dec 112
original 113 dec2hex 00000071 hex2dec 113
original 114 dec2hex 00000072 hex2dec 114
original 115 dec2hex 00000073 hex2dec 115
original 116 dec2hex 00000074 hex2dec 116
original 117 dec2hex 00000075 hex2dec 117
original 118 dec2hex 00000076 hex2dec 118
original 119 dec2hex 00000077 hex2dec 119
original 120 dec2hex 00000078 hex2dec 120
original 121 dec2hex 00000079 hex2dec 121
original 122 dec2hex 0000007A hex2dec 122
original 123 dec2hex 0000007B hex2dec 123
original 124 dec2hex 0000007C hex2dec 124
original 125 dec2hex 0000007D hex2dec 125
original 126 dec2hex 0000007E hex2dec 126
original 127 dec2hex 0000007F hex2dec 127
original 128 dec2hex 00000080 hex2dec 128
original 129 dec2hex 00000081 hex2dec 129
original 130 dec2hex 00000082 hex2dec 130
original 131 dec2hex 00000083 hex2dec 131
original 132 dec2hex 00000084 hex2dec 132
original 133 dec2hex 00000085 hex2dec 133
original 134 dec2hex 00000086 hex2dec 134
original 135 dec2hex 00000087 hex2dec 135
original 136 dec2hex 00000088 hex2dec 136
original 137 dec2hex 00000089 hex2dec 137
original 138 dec2hex 0000008A hex2dec 138
original 139 dec2hex 0000008B hex2dec 139
original 140 dec2hex 0000008C hex2dec 140
original 141 dec2hex 0000008D hex2dec 141
original 142 dec2hex 0000008E hex2dec 142
original 143 dec2hex 0000008F hex2dec 143
original 144 dec2hex 00000090 hex2dec 144
original 145 dec2hex 00000091 hex2dec 145
original 146 dec2hex 00000092 hex2dec 146
original 147 dec2hex 00000093 hex2dec 147
original 148 dec2hex 00000094 hex2dec 148
original 149 dec2hex 00000095 hex2dec 149
original 150 dec2hex 00000096 hex2dec 150
original 151 dec2hex 00000097 hex2dec 151
original 152 dec2hex 00000098 hex2dec 152
original 153 dec2hex 00000099 hex2dec 153
original 154 dec2hex 0000009A hex2dec 154
original 155 dec2hex 0000009B hex2dec 155
original 156 dec2hex 0000009C hex2dec 156
original 157 dec2hex 0000009D hex2dec 157
original 158 dec2hex 0000009E hex2dec 158
original 159 dec2hex 0000009F hex2dec 159
original 160 dec2hex 000000A0 hex2dec 160
original 161 dec2hex 000000A1 hex2dec 161
original 162 dec2hex 000000A2 hex2dec 162
original 163 dec2hex 000000A3 hex2dec 163
original 164 dec2hex 000000A4 hex2dec 164
original 165 dec2hex 000000A5 hex2dec 165
original 166 dec2hex 000000A6 hex2dec 166
original 167 dec2hex 000000A7 hex2dec 167
original 168 dec2hex 000000A8 hex2dec 168
original 169 dec2hex 000000A9 hex2dec 169
original 170 dec2hex 000000AA hex2dec 170
original 171 dec2hex 000000AB hex2dec 171
original 172 dec2hex 000000AC hex2dec 172
original 173 dec2hex 000000AD hex2dec 173
original 174 dec2hex 000000AE hex2dec 174
original 175 dec2hex 000000AF hex2dec 175
original 176 dec2hex 000000B0 hex2dec 176
original 177 dec2hex 000000B1 hex2dec 177
original 178 dec2hex 000000B2 hex2dec 178
original 179 dec2hex 000000B3 hex2dec 179
original 180 dec2hex 000000B4 hex2dec 180
original 181 dec2hex 000000B5 hex2dec 181
original 182 dec2hex 000000B6 hex2dec 182
original 183 dec2hex 000000B7 hex2dec 183
original 184 dec2hex 000000B8 hex2dec 184
original 185 dec2hex 000000B9 hex2dec 185
original 186 dec2hex 000000BA hex2dec 186
original 187 dec2hex 000000BB hex2dec 187
original 188 dec2hex 000000BC hex2dec 188
original 189 dec2hex 000000BD hex2dec 189
original 190 dec2hex 000000BE hex2dec 190
original 191 dec2hex 000000BF hex2dec 191
original 192 dec2hex 000000C0 hex2dec 192
original 193 dec2hex 000000C1 hex2dec 193
original 194 dec2hex 000000C2 hex2dec 194
original 195 dec2hex 000000C3 hex2dec 195
original 196 dec2hex 000000C4 hex2dec 196
original 197 dec2hex 000000C5 hex2dec 197
original 198 dec2hex 000000C6 hex2dec 198
original 199 dec2hex 000000C7 hex2dec 199
original 200 dec2hex 000000C8 hex2dec 200
original 201 dec2hex 000000C9 hex2dec 201
original 202 dec2hex 000000CA hex2dec 202
original 203 dec2hex 000000CB hex2dec 203
original 204 dec2hex 000000CC hex2dec 204
original 205 dec2hex 000000CD hex2dec 205
original 206 dec2hex 000000CE hex2dec 206
original 207 dec2hex 000000CF hex2dec 207
original 208 dec2hex 000000D0 hex2dec 208
original 209 dec2hex 000000D1 hex2dec 209
original 210 dec2hex 000000D2 hex2dec 210
original 211 dec2hex 000000D3 hex2dec 211
original 212 dec2hex 000000D4 hex2dec 212
original 213 dec2hex 000000D5 hex2dec 213
original 214 dec2hex 000000D6 hex2dec 214
original 215 dec2hex 000000D7 hex2dec 215
original 216 dec2hex 000000D8 hex2dec 216
original 217 dec2hex 000000D9 hex2dec 217
original 218 dec2hex 000000DA hex2dec 218
original 219 dec2hex 000000DB hex2dec 219
original 220 dec2hex 000000DC hex2dec 220
original 221 dec2hex 000000DD hex2dec 221
original 222 dec2hex 000000DE hex2dec 222
original 223 dec2hex 000000DF hex2dec 223
original 224 dec2hex 000000E0 hex2dec 224
original 225 dec2hex 000000E1 hex2dec 225
original 226 dec2hex 000000E2 hex2dec 226
original 227 dec2hex 000000E3 hex2dec 227
original 228 dec2hex 000000E4 hex2dec 228
original 229 dec2hex 000000E5 hex2dec 229
original 230 dec2hex 000000E6 hex2dec 230
original 231 dec2hex 000000E7 hex2dec 231
original 232 dec2hex 000000E8 hex2dec 232
original 233 dec2hex 000000E9 hex2dec 233
original 234 dec2hex 000000EA hex2dec 234
original 235 dec2hex 000000EB hex2dec 235
original 236 dec2hex 000000EC hex2dec 236
original 237 dec2hex 000000ED hex2dec 237
original 238 dec2hex 000000EE hex2dec 238
original 239 dec2hex 000000EF hex2dec 239
original 240 dec2hex 000000F0 hex2dec 240
original 241 dec2hex 000000F1 hex2dec 241
original 242 dec2hex 000000F2 hex2dec 242
original 243 dec2hex 000000F3 hex2dec 243
original 244 dec2hex 000000F4 hex2dec 244
original 245 dec2hex 000000F5 hex2dec 245
original 246 dec2hex 000000F6 hex2dec 246
original 247 dec2hex 000000F7 hex2dec 247
original 248 dec2hex 000000F8 hex2dec 248
original 249 dec2hex 000000F9 hex2dec 249
original 250 dec2hex 000000FA hex2dec 250
original 251 dec2hex 000000FB hex2dec 251
original 252 dec2hex 000000FC hex2dec 252
original 253 dec2hex 000000FD hex2dec 253
original 254 dec2hex 000000FE hex2dec 254
original 255 dec2hex 000000FF hex2dec 255
```